# setFont not working in this order

Tags: java

why the setFont isnt working when its written like this? I want to draw message(font bold, size 20) and under it a multiplication table with small blue numbers.

```
//this is a separate class
public class Start {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    GUI gui = new GUI();
  }
}

public class GUI extends JFrame{
  public GUI(){
    add(new DrawTable());

    setTitle("Multiplication table");
    setSize(240, 280);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
  }
}

class DrawTable extends JPanel{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);



    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    for(int i = 1, j = 110; i < 10; i++, j += 15){
        g.drawString("" + i, 20, j);
    }
    for(int i = 1, j = 50; i < 10; i++, j += 20){
        g.drawString("" + i, j, 80);
    }
    for(int i = 1, j = 110; i < 10; i++, j += 15){
        for(int k = 1, l = 50; k < 10 ; k++, l += 20){
            if((i * k) < 10){
                g.drawString("" + i *k , l, j);
            }else{
                g.drawString("" + i * k, l - 6, j);
            }
        }
    }

//those are the lines im talking about

    setFont(new Font("font1", Font.BOLD, 20));
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int x = (getWidth() / 2) - (fm.stringWidth("Multiplication table"))/2;
    g.drawString("Multiplication table", x, 50);
  }
}
```

This only works if i put these four lines under the super.paintComponent(g), then
the message is black, bold and 20 and the numbers small and blue, but if i put the 4 
lines down like here, its all small and blue, why?

Comment: What is "font1" by the way? Does your system have this font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling `setFont(...)` on the Graphics variable, g, under your comment. For the font to work, it should be:

```
g.setFont(...);
```

i.e., change

```
setFont(new Font("font1", Font.BOLD, 20));
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
int x = (getWidth() / 2) - (fm.stringWidth("Multiplication table"))/2;
g.drawString("Multiplication table", x, 50);
```

to:

```
g.setFont(new Font("font1", Font.BOLD, 20));
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
int x = (getWidth() / 2) - (fm.stringWidth("Multiplication table"))/2;
g.drawString("Multiplication table", x, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
g.setFont(new Font("//Font name", 1, 20));
```

1 is the style you want (you can try as many as you want until you find one you like) and 20 is the font size.